# How can a promise be used to fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

The goal is to have `theQuery` function handle the query and return an array of the rows back to `result`. In the `theQuery` function `console.log` works as expected, but logging result logs `undefined`. The `undefined` log occurs first on the the terminal. How can a promise be used to fix this?

```
"use strict";
var pg = require('pg').native;
var connectionString = "...";
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

function theQuery(table,column) {
  client.query('SELECT * FROM "'+table+'" WHERE column = '+"'"+column+"';", function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
      console.log(result.rows);//works logs the rows
      return result.rows;
  });
}


  let Query = theQuery("table", "column);
  console.log(result);// logs undefined
```

Comment: You are trying to return a value from a callback function. This indicates a profound misunderstanding about asynchronous code. Refer to the duplicate thread.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call but I could not get them working that is why I am specifically asking about promises and how to implement them in this case.

Comment: "I could not get them working" is by far not enough to go on. The other thread goes into specific detail about how asynchronous programming works, there is no way you have tried everything in there in such a short time.

Comment: How to use promises is exactly explained in the linked question. There are also links for further information. See the "Use promises" section. The example couldn't be any simpler.

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) already does everything you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
"use strict";
var pg = require('pg').native;
var connectionString = "...";
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

function theQuery(table,column) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
        client.query('SELECT * FROM "'+table+'" WHERE column = '+"'"+column+"';", function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                reject(console.error('error running query', err));
            }
            console.log(result.rows);//works logs the rows
            fulfill(result.rows);
        });
    });
}


theQuery("table", "column).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```